# How to identify a bug in Ubuntu?

Tags: bug-reporting

Sometimes users come across problems which may be a **bug** or other **software/system issues**, and cannot differentiate between the two.
So how can one determine whether a problem occuring in an Ubuntu system is a bug or it's just some trouble in software/hardware?

Comment: Why a downvote to this Q?

Answer (score 2):

1. If there is an error message, read it carefully. If possible, copy it or record it. While you are at it, record the *exact sequence* of steps or commands to reach the error message.
2. Search for an answer. Start with your favorite search engine - Ubuntu help sites are all indexed by them. Be wary of answers more than two years old - Ubuntu has changed a lot in a few years.

   Start by searching for the exact text of the error. It's very likely somebody has trodden the path before you.
3. If there is no satisfying answer, then ask for help (here, of course).
4. If the help here determines that you have a bug, search for the bug at Launchpad.net, home to Ubuntu's bug tracker. It's likely that somebody has already reported the bug - simply subscribe to the bug report, don't leave any distracting 'me too' comments. If nobody has reported the bug, ask for help (here) to report it properly - it's not easy the first time.